# How Can I get a Particular User Group Name in Django Form Query

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form with a Drop Down from User Groups which is Created from Django Admin Panel. I have 3 groups with various permissions so in this form I want to get only the Group named **'Guest'**  from the drop down and disabled.
What is the best way of doing it.

Below is what I have tried but I am getting the following errors:
**ImportError: cannot import name 'getgroups' from 'os'**

```
class GuestUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.get('Guest'),
                               required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'group']
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but you also missed a `()` at `email = forms.EmailField()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `User` model has a field named `groups`, so *plural*. You can work with a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) and only retain a single element: the group named `Guest`:

```
class GuestUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    group = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Group.objects.filter(name='Guest'),
        initial=Group.objects.filter(name='Guest'),
        disabled=True
    )

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'groups']
```